# Visual Studio 2017 (any edition) not longer able to install or update on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-10

I have the problem that I cannot update or install Visual Studio anymore on my system.

Today I saw that a newer Visual Studio 2017 version was released and I tried to start the VS installer for the update process. The start for the installer was just spinning but nothing happened. After that I tried to start the installer separately from VS but it didn't work either.
So I continued to make an even bigger mistake by assuming my installed version is bad and to completely reinstall Visual Studio by uninstalling and then trying to start the normal installation process.
Unfortunately it didn't work.

After downloading the webinstaller, it downloads the installer packages it needs but the vs_installer.exe itself will never run successfully afterwards (also if started manually).
There is no error shown directly. It just does not start. The EventViewer is also not showing any errors I would say have a connection to the problem.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: switch DNS server in network settings to google/Cloudflare DNS

Comment: It has no effect unfortunately. I also tried to change the network (to one of our WLAN networks) earlier.

Comment: already tried to run the `InstallCleanup.exe`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Found the problem and will add the solution shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of communication with the Visual Studio team they pointed me to the only thing they know could cause this issue.

Some time ago I added an environment variable to my system named NODE_OPTIONS. It was necessary because the builds of our Angular applications are so big that we had to adjust the available memory size.

Removing the environment variable enabled me to start vs_installer.exe and to reinstall Visual Studio again.

It's a bit obscure and not many people will have this problem. But I hope Microsoft will fix it anyway.

P.S. The silent crash is caused by the usage of Electron for the Visual Studio installer. The person from Microsoft, who helped me to workaround the problem, told me that they are working on a fix.